# django rest 3.1.1 - one to many serializer with "many" attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, models, serialization

I want to create a simple serializer that everyone who want will be able to add a Question with multi Answers (how many that he want)

one Question- multi Answers

- I want to be able to add with the build in html form and not to edit the json.

my models:

```
    class Question(models.Model):
         question_text = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Answer(models.Model):
         question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
         answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

my url.py

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('answer_text',)


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text', 'answers',)

class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

now, when i run the web I get the message:

> "Lists are not currently supported in HTML input."

please help :)

**first edit**

even when i remove the ('many=True') i get an error while trying to post:

> AssertionError at /questions/
>   The `.create()` method does not support writable nestedfields by default.
>        Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `api_project2.urls.QuestionSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on
>   nested serializer fields.

thats creates m second problem: the create() method that i dont knwo how to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you remove the ('many=True'), you get an error while trying to post because you have not rewrite the function create, you should rewrite the function create

Answer (score 1):

Your quote answers your question. The built-in HTML view input forms do not support lists.

It seems that support was [planned for 3.1](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers-as-html-forms) but I don't see any mention in the [3.1 release notes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/).